Error handling for singly linked list in C
I have seen many list implementations in C in this site; I know its been asked many times.  I need some advice regarding:

Quality of my code, especially my list library.
How to handle errors in main (should every error be handled in main()?).
Can I handle errors within functions by calling exit (EXIT_FAILURE)? Some say it is bad practice since they have side effects.
Allocation errors, Read errors, function operation errors (how to handle?).
In case of errors, how should I release memory? There may be multiple lists, nodes.
Should I provide a message within each function in my library or give return values? (I like to give freedom to programmer to give message; is that bad?)
I have typedefed list and allocated structure in heap; is it okay?

I have tried to explicitly check errors by if/else conditionals but they began to cluster too much, leading to bad code.
list.h
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    #include <stdio.h>
    #define ALLOC_FAIL NULL

    typedef struct ListNode{
        int data;
        struct ListNode* next;
    }node;

    typedef struct LinkedList{
        node* head;
        node* tail;
        size_t size;
    }list;

    list* createList(void);                   // allocation operations returns list or node //
    node* getNode(int data);                 //  else returns ALLOC_FAIL on failure // 

    node* insertAtFront(list* l,node* newnode);
    node* insertAtLast(list*l,node* newnode);
    node* nodeAt(list* l,size_t position);                     // node operations returns the        // 
    node* insertNode(list* l,node* newnode,node* current);    //inserted node upon success else NULL //        
    node* insertBefore(list*l,node* newnode,int searchData);
    node* insertAfter(list*l,node* newnode,int searchData);
    node* insertAtIndex(list* l,node* newnode,size_t index);

    void printList(list* l);
    void* destroyList(list* l);       // returns NULL to clear the list variable //

#ifdef __cplusplus
}

#endif
#endif // LIST_H

list.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "list.h"

 // All functions expect allocated memory ,it is up to the programmer to handle memory errors or leaks// 

list* createList(void)
{   
    list* l = malloc(sizeof(list));

    if(!l)
        return ALLOC_FAIL;

    l->head  = l->tail = NULL;
    l->size  = 0;

    return l;
}

node* getNode(int data) 
{    
    node* newnode = malloc(sizeof(node)); 

    if(!newnode)
        return ALLOC_FAIL;

    newnode->data = data;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    
    return newnode;
}

node* insertAtFront(list* l,node* newnode)
{   
    if(l->head)
        newnode->next = l->head;
    else
        l->tail = newnode;

     ++l->size; 
    return l->head = newnode;           
}

node* insertAtLast(list* l,node* newnode)
{       
    if(l->tail)
        l->tail->next = newnode;
    else
        l->head = newnode;

    ++l->size;      
    return l->tail = newnode;           
}

node* insertNode(list* l,node* newnode,node* current)
{
    if(!current)
        return NULL;

    newnode->next = current->next;
    current->next = newnode;

    ++l->size;
    return newnode; 
}

node* insertBefore(list* l,node* newnode,int searchData)
{
    node* current = l->head,*previous = l->head;

    if(!l->head)
        return NULL;

    if(l->head->data == searchData) 
        return insertAtFront(l,newnode);

    while((current = current->next)){

        if(current->data == searchData)
            return insertNode(l,newnode,previous);  

        previous = current;     
    }
    return NULL;    
}

node* insertAfter(list* l,node* newnode,int searchData)
{
    node* current = l->head;

    while(current){

        if(current->data == searchData)
            break;

        current = current->next;        
    }    

    return insertNode(l,newnode,current);    
}
    
node* insertAtIndex(list* l,node* newnode,size_t index)    
{    
    node* current = l->head;
    
    if(index == 0)    
        return insertAtFront(l,newnode);
    
    while(current && --index)    
        current = current->next;

    return insertNode(l,newnode,current);      // insertNode will handle if current is NULL //      
}

node* nodeAt(list* l,size_t position)    
{           
    node* current = l->head;
    
    while(current && position--)
            current = current->next;        

    return current; 
}

void printList(list* l)    
{
    node* current = l->head;

    printf("\n[");

    while(current){
        printf(" %d ,",current->data);
        current = current->next;            // prints [] if list is empty // 
    }

    printf("]\n");  
}

void* destroyList(list* l)    
{
    node* current;

    while((current = l->head)){
        l->head = l->head->next;
        free(current);  
    }

    return NULL;     // null initialize the list variable in main // 
}

main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "list.h"

static void error(char* errMsg);
static bool usrInput(char* msg,int* location);
static void clearBuffer(void);

int main(void)
{
    size_t size = 5;
    int data,index;
    bool readSuccess;
    node* newnode, *insertedNode;

    list* l = createList();

    if(!l){ 
        error("List allocation failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

            

    //inserting into list //    

    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i){

        readSuccess = usrInput("Enter your data :",&data);
        if(!readSuccess)
            return EXIT_FAILURE;  // mem leak1 ?? Any memory leaks? os will release memory ?//

        newnode = getNode(data);
    
        if(!newnode){
            error("Newnode allocation failed");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;  // mem leak2 ?? // 
        }       

        insertAtLast(l,newnode);
    }

    printf("\nYour intial list is : \n");   
    printList(l);           


    // inserting at an index //    

    readSuccess = usrInput("Enter position : ",&index);         
    if(!readSuccess)   
        return EXIT_FAILURE;                

    readSuccess = usrInput("Enter your data :",&data);   
    if(!readSuccess)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    newnode = getNode(data);                     // same code repetition! should i provide wrapper function?//

    if(!newnode){
        error("Newnode allocation failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;  
     }      

    insertedNode = insertAtIndex(l,newnode,index);

    if(!insertedNode){
        error("No such position found in list");
        free(newnode);
    }
    else            
        printf("\nYour new list is : \n");  

    printList(l);   

    l = destroyList(l);  // initializing l to null (avoiding bad pointer) //


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

static void error(char* errMsg)
{
    fprintf(stdout,"\nError : %s\n",errMsg);
}

static void clearBuffer(void){
    while(getchar() != '\n');
}

static bool usrInput(char* msg,int* location)
{
    bool readStatus = false;

    printf("\n%s\n",msg);

    if(scanf("%4d",location) == 1)
        readStatus = true;
    else
        fprintf(stdout,"\nERROR reading input!\nPlease enter an integer value within range\n");

    clearBuffer();      
    return readStatus;      
}


Not asked for, but... The extra flourish of ending single line comments with another pair of characters (//) is, you know, unnecessary. Spend more time ensuring legibility with consistent // yadda-yadda using a single space after the leading // for easy reading... Pointless flourishes like this seem harmless, but are, in fact, annoying (ie: distracting) to the reader. (How many times is <stdio.h> included in each compilation unit? (ie: source file that is compiled.)

@Harith mind your language !this is a community where people asks doubts. "your stupid function" ??

Great questions!

Quality of my code, especially my list library

Having the caller allocate the newnode and pass them in is a bad idea, especially since you cannot detect whether a node was allocated by malloc() and do not detect whether it already has an empty tail, nor do you have any way to report invalid input.  It also moves the boilerplate allocation and error-handling code to every call site.

How to handle errors in main (should every errors be handled in main?).

Currently, the only error you report (or even can report) is an out-of-memory error, which your client might want to handle in several ways: by freeing some memory and retrying, by unwinding the operation that it was creating the list as part of and reporting failure, or by terminating the program. Therefore, report errors to the caller.
It would be better to take the data and allocate the node from that, although you might want something a little more generic.

Can I handle errors within functions by calling exit (EXIT_FAILURE)? Some say it is bad practice since they have side effects.

This is too rigid. I frequently write an error-handler like
/* Abort with an error message that includes the line number, the system
 * error string, and what the program was doing.
 */
void fatal_system_error_helper( const char* const msg,
                                const char* const sourcefile,
                                const int line,
                                const int err )
{
    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf( stderr,
             "Error %s (%s:%d): %s\n",
             msg,
             sourcefile,
             line,
             strerror(err) );
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

#define fatal_system_error(msg) \
  fatal_system_error_helper( (msg), __FILE__, __LINE__, errno )

I can then test the return value for error and call that to abort the program.  If the error was not caused by a system call that sets errno, I can simplify this by removing the err parameter and the call to strerror().

Allocation errors, Read errors, function operation errors (how to handle?)

You currently give ALLOC_FAIL a name that suggests there are other types of errors, but you don’t define any, and there are no other special values that could represent different errors.  If there is only one error code, it mught as well be NULL.  That is what NULL is.  If you mean to report other types of errors, you might:

return a success/error code, and write the new list to a list** output parameter or just update the existing list in place on success.  (This is by far the most common approach.)
return a struct (or discriminated union) containing an error code and a result. This lets you return additional information on error, such as the last node successfully added.
Allocate an array of dummy objects representing errors, guaranteeing those values can not point to valid nodes or lists. If passed a node, check whether it is an error code by testing whether it is within the array.
Or I guess you could set errno


In case of errors, how should i release memory since there may be multiple lists, nodes.

You currently don’t seem to have any functions that insert or delete more than a single node, although it’s possible I overlooked them.  A minimalist approach, of only updating the list if the operation succeeds, would work for you here.  Failing that, there is no point in reporting a detailed error to the caller unless you have left the list in a known, recoverable state.

should i provide message within each functions in my library or give return values? (I like to give freedom to programmer to give message ,is it bad?)

If this is meant to be a useful library, make it convenient to turn an error code into an error message, but let the user decide whether to.  Instrumenting the library, by printing messages to stderr that might be turned on by a #define, could be useful for debugging.

I have typedefed list and allocated structure in heap is it ok ?

The typedef is fine until you need a list of something other than int, and then you either want void* data or a different name.
I would recommend you do all allocation and deallocation through your API, to make memory-corruption bugs at least slightly less easy to write by mistake. You are going to end up allocating all inserted nodes on the heap: They cannot be either static or local and if you were using an arena allocator, you would change to an array-based implementation anyway.

Tip about "Error %s (%s:%d): %s\n": An error handle should assume little.  Consider sentinels "Error \"%s\" (\"%s\":%d): \"%s\"\n" for the strings (to better see leading trialing white-space) and perhaps even pre-test pointers for null-ness.

I allocated node in main since they can be removed from a list(returns the removed node) and directly appended to another list which allows flexibility in removal and insertion also i can avoid repeated calls to malloc.  ALLOC_FAIL and NULL were introduced to distinguish allocation failure(null) and function operation failure(null) to the reader. If i have 1000 lists in memory and during the the next allocation or read failure i exited program directly as you mentioned will it create any memory problems

"Allocate an array of dummy objects representing errors, ... check whether it is an error code by testing whether it is within the array." Compare EVERY returned ptr as being equal to one of the array's elements addresses??? That will slow things down nicely! Suggest, instead, twinning the manifest errno with a "global" myListErrno, then just set its value to be non-zero, instead... :-)

@chux-ReinstateMonica Since the format strings here are always hardcoded string constants, it didn’t feel necessary. I’m not really worried about another maintainer introducing a string with a : followed by a \n, and at that point, they could just throw in a \" anyway. Barring something that intentionally misleading, the final : on a line always introduces the strerror() message. Although, feel free to tweak it to your heart’s content.

@Fe2O3 It’s only two comparisons, wrapped in a function or macro. A global error value is not thread-safe.

@Sai_krishna If that’s an important optimization, you might want to add either A: a function to move a node from one list to another, or B: a function that extracts a node as a singleton, which you can then splice into another list.

@Davislor Okay... If each thread handles its own list (or collection of them) to be "thread safe", then wire the error variable into the head of the list beside the two pointers and the count variables. There's always a way. There's always lots of ways that things can go wrong, and usually only one way that things go right... Cheers! :-)

@Fe2O3 That’s a solution. More likely, though, the error code is the return value, except in functions that return a node* to mark a position, in which case NULL means not found.


Quality of my code, especially my list library.

OK for a learner, yet needs work.

How to handle errors in main (should every errors be handled in main?).

list.c/h is the library.  main() here is just an illustrative use.  Errors should be handled in the calling code of your list functions.  In this case: main().

Can I handle errors within functions by calling exit (EXIT_FAILURE)?  Some say it is bad practice since they have side effects.

Avoid such a black-hole.  Return an error indication.

Allocation errors, Read errors, function operation errors (how to handle?).

Return an error indication.  I'd consider a re-write where the vast majority of functions return an error flag.

In case of errors, how should i release memory since there may be multiple lists, nodes.

Do not release memory.

should i provide message within each functions in my library or give return values? (I like to give freedom to programmer to give message ,is it bad?)

Do not print.  Return an error indication.

I have typedefed list and allocated structure in heap is it ok ?

See below comments.


Rather than exposing node to public use, consider hiding it.  This change is impactful.

I'd expect destroyList(NULL) to be OK.

Consider not printing a ',' after the last node in printList().

Rather that using names all over the place in list.h, like ListNode, node, insertAtFront, printList, ..., consider using a common prefix list_Node, list_insertAtFront, list_print.

Use const when list does not change: printList(list* l)) --> printList(const list* l).

Add a function to report list length size_t list_length(const list* l)

Add function to delete the head of the list.

Add function to delete the tail of the list.

Rather than allocate to the type size, allocate to the size of the object.


//newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
newnode = malloc(sizeof *newnode);


what does last point mean allocate to the size of object? sizeof(node) will allocate memory for all variables right?? also if my lib functions return an error code every time can i use a error handler function to display errrMsg and call exit(EXIT_FAILURE) like the one provide by Davislor answer

@Sai_krishna (Presuming to answer for #Chux...) Consider int *p = malloc(sizeof(int)); A too-common bug is a stressed-out coder changing int *p to long *p and neglecting to change the 2nd instance of int on that one line... The compiler knows the size of the variable that has been declared, yet the coder has overlooked a necessary change. The second version is preferred, and often safer to use. Consider it "recommended practise by those who've gone before"... (Hi Chux! Hope I did alright, here! :-)

@Fe2O3 Well said.  @Sai_krishna, code could use an error handler function in the calling code (main()) but not in the library ones (list.c).  Also concerning allocate to the size of the object: if you see p_ptr = malloc(sizeof q_type) and p_ptr = malloc(sizeof *p_ptr), which is easier to review?

One line from main():
    node* newnode, *insertedNode;


the whitespace and the splats
the mix of lowercase and camel case variable names
both are not needed until later in the function (not proximate to use)

Some guidelines insist that each variable be declared/defined on its own line:
    node* newnode;
    node* insertedNode;

This could make the location of the splats less of an issue.
Recommend using the style wherein the splat is "hard up against" the variable name, not the datatype.
(It's contentious as individuals each, rightly, have their experiences and their opinions.)
However, when you reach the stage of "pointers to functions", you'll be writing:
    int (*func)(int, int); // ptr to func taking 2 int's and returning an int

Since int* p; is the same as int *p;, but the latter is consistent with more advanced requirements, using the latter style everywhere will aid writing consistent code.
Uninitialised variables are loose cannons. Try to limit the scope of variables:
    node *newNode = NULL;


"especially my list library"
If each of these (library) functions can be called independently of the others, then each function needs to robustly check that its parameters make sense (to the extent that it can.)
node *insertAtFront( list *l, node *pnode )
{
    if( l == NULL || pnode == NULL )
        /* return some kind of error code. */

See Commandment II of this list
(Depending on conformance to versions of the C Standard, NULL may no longer be appropriate.)

Learn and exploit Standard Library functions
Here are the first two functions of list.c written with less code.
list *createList( void ) {
    return (list*)calloc( 1, sizeof(list) ); // optional cast in C; required for C++
}

node *getNode( int data ) {
    node *p = calloc( 1, sizeof *p );

    if( p ) p->data = data;

    return p;
}

This means that the token ALLOC_FAIL is no longer used and could be removed from list.h.
Every line of code that is NOT required (and not present) is a line of code whose potential bug will not plague your program now or in the future.
Exercise:
Rewrite insertBefore() to use a for() loop so that current and previous are scoped to only exist for the span of that loop, not the entire function. Perhaps use much, much shorter variable names as their existence is so brief, yet purpose easily discernable.

In the few code samples shown here, I've used my own unconventional style of whitespace around parentheses just to demonstrate an alternative.
When working with others in a large codebase, go with the flow so that all the code can be read as belonging to one style. When writing for yourself only, it's okay to follow your own tastes and preferences. My preference is to make tokens and operations on those tokens as visible as possible.

Oops!
    l = destroyList(l);  // initializing l to null (avoiding bad pointer) //

The code has just set the pointer variable l to NULL without free()ing the block of heap that holds the struct list values.
That's how easy it is for the coder and, so far, 3 reviewers to overlook a bug (memory leak).

Do i need to check the list and node variables in my lib?, because since allocating both in program requires error handling and explicitly checking return values .also if there were many modules and sub modules in my lib using list and node variables i would have to check every time for the validity of arguments,( which will create conditional overhead ,idk for sure??)    also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256220/calloc-usefulness-of-zeroing-out-memory  answers of this question says calloc() pointers != NULL

@Sai_krishna "Coders never do stupid things, like accidentally delete (or not delete) that one line of code that's not currently visible, or mistakenly indent one-too-many times and presume a line in under the control of a preceding if()..." You can validate pointers to whatever extent you're prepared to accept the responsibility/risk... The responses to the question you've linked like to address some "unicorn" implementations that you're unlikely to encounter in your career... SO is full of pedantry... Keep a grain of salt near the keyboard. It comes in handy, too often... Cheers! :-)
